# Bundled JRE error with install4j installer packaged as msix

Tags: install4j

We create an installer with install4j that bundles the JRE.  We then use the MSIX Packaging Tool to create a .msix installer, to publish on the Microsoft App Store.

When we install the .msix package for testing and try to run the application, we get the following error:

"The JVM found at .\jre is damaged.  Please reinstall or define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 64-bit JDK or JRE"

Note that the JRE is bundled with the installer, and it is actually installed in a folder called "jre" under the installation folder.

When we install from the .exe installer, everything works fine, this problem only happens after we create a .msix installer with the MSIX Packaging Tool.  We've checked all the installed files and everything looks fine, but the launcher will not run.

Has anybody seen this problem?  And is there a solution or workaround?

Comment: We got the same problem. It works locally when we install the *.msix file. However, Microsoft does seem to get that same error when testing the Microsoft Store version we uploaded (the same we can install locally).